# JSON/EJSON Error w/ Stripe API - Invoice Webhook Event

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, meteor, webhooks

Update w/ Additional Info - 18 Dec.

As I test further it appears that the error is isolated to the "this.response.end(json);" See notes below:

stripe non-invoice event: 
a) "this.response.end(EJSON.stringify(obj, {indent: true}));" works & returns 200 
b) "this.response.end(EJSON.stringify(obj));" no error on local server, error on stripe dashboard with 'unable to connect' and does not return code 200

stripe invoice event: 
a) "this.response.end(EJSON.stringify(obj, {indent: true}));" throws errors - see details below. 
b) "this.response.end(EJSON.stringify(obj));" no error on local server, error on stripe dashboard with 'unable to connect' and does not return code 200

Any insight would be appreciated.

I am having some issues with the Stripe API and am seeking some help or insight. I am using `ngrok` to test the Stripe webhooks locally and everything works fine until I make a request to any Stripe 'invoice' event type (e.g. invoice.payment_succeeded). When I run a test on any 'invoice' event type I get several errors:

1. my running application breaks (i.e. requires me to type meteor run in the terminal to restart the app)
2. I receive this server side error message in my terminal:

```bash
///error message start///
events.js:183
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error: write after end
   at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:622:15)
   at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:617:10)
   at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:475:10)
   at flow (_stream_readable.js:846:34)
   at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:828:3)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
///error message end///
```

3. On my Stripe dashboard I get an error: `'Test webhook error: Unable to connect'`

Again this only breaks when I make a request to any Stripe `'invoice'` event type (e.g. `invoice.payment_succeeded`).

I contacted Stripe to see if there was anything else I should consider but they said things were fine on their end.

One final point, to get `ngrok` running I use `'ngrok http 3000'`.

With that said my server side webhook code is below. If anyone has any insight on what would be causing this error, any insight perspective would be appreciated.

```js
///server side webhook code start///
Router.route('/webhooks/stripe', { where: 'server' })
   .get(function () {
       console.log('getter');
       this.response.end('closing...');
   })
   .post(function () {
       console.log('post function initiated');

       // stores payload as string
       var obj = this.request.body;

       console.log("print obj var");
       console.log(obj);

       // saves as indented string to send as response
       var json = EJSON.stringify(obj, {indent: true});

       this.response.writeHead(200, {
           'Content-Length': json.length,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       });

       this.response.end(json);
   })
   .put(function () {
       console.log('put');
   });

///server side webhook code end///
```

Comment: Just curious, until which step it throws the error? Is `console.log(obj);` print anything before the error is thrown?

Comment: Hi @wsw. it throws an error at "this.response.end(json);" I was able to confirm this via a few console logs. The strange thing for me is that the code was working earlier in the day and then all of a sudden for the invoice event type the code would break and throw the error - all other event types would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. For reference and posterity I removed the commented code below and manually added my status code (i.e.        this.response.statusCode = 200;). This got things working and resolved the issue.

```
///code snippet start///
var json = EJSON.stringify(obj, {indent: true});

   //this is the code i removed
       // this.response.writeHead(200, {
       //     'Content-Length': json.length,
       //     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       // });

   //this is the code i added to send a manual status code
       this.response.statusCode = 200;

       this.response.end(json);
///code snippet end///
```